# How to insert UILabel in UIText?

Tags: iphone

Can we insert UILabel in UItext in I phone App? is it possible? if yes how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of inserting that label in the UIText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField? UITextView? in any case it's a bad idea. If you are doing it to change the font within the same view you can look at the [EGOTextView](http://cocoaobjects.com/egotextview/) or [JTextView](http://cocoaobjects.com/jtextview/).

Comment: Jbat.......were as i want to place the UILabel on a image and check whether i placed the UILabel on right place.. so i thought i can create UIText on image and move UILabel using UITouch and try to place it on UIText and match it by "if condition".

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a UITextField then you can do it "visually" using the interface builder though Apple advises against it.